# CoreData - Does changing one side of relation ship effects the other side

Tags: ios, core-data, relationship

I have a one to many relationship between Animal and Exhibit.
One Exhibit can contain many animals.

1. Does changing the animal exhibit will automatically change the other side and remove the animal from the exhibit, or should I do from the other side too?
2. Does setting `exhibit.animals = nil` removes all the relationships ?

Thanks

Shani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, if you have reverse relationship between Exhibit and Animal
2. Yes, it will delete all the relationships, but wether it deletes the Exhibits themselfe, depends on Delete Rule.

Comment: Thanks. what should be the delete rule so they want be deleted ?

Comment: Cascade, i guess. Here is the docs on the Delete Rules https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html